# How to make a translucent appbar flutter

Tags: flutter

How to make a translucent appbar with flutter?

I need to create an app bar but I do not know where to start.

exemple:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqU64.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to make a scaffold layout with a translucent app bar:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class TranslucentExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        // Overrides the standard translucent status bar.
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
          // Remove any elevation to avoid seeing a shadow underneath the translucent material of the app bar.
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: Text('Photo frame'),
          action: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              tooltip: 'Settings',
              onPressed: () => print('something'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // You might have to change the fit of the image to make it 'full screen'.
        body: Image.network('url.to/image'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it isn't possible to fully recreate the screenshot you provided since it currently isn't possible to have a transparent or translucent navigation bar on Android with Flutter apps.

Answer (score 1):

Only add extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,

like:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Photo"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
  ),
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  body: Container(),
);
```